# Convertir String-Hexadecimal A String

Tags: javascript, nodejs, string

Buen Dia

tengo un PDF convirtiendolo en JSON con el modulo "pdf2json" , hasta aca todo esta Bien pero cuando quiero leer el campo de Texto/String ya identificado , el valor es "**BRINGCO%20S.A.**"

Evidentemente luego del caracter "%" es el valor Hexadecimal de espacio " "=="%20".

Tengo la Duda si hay alguna funcion o metodo String directo que me devuelva la cadena convertida de acuerdo si tiene estos Valores Hexadeciaml.

Ejemplo : "**BRINGCO%20S.A.**" ---> "**BRINGCO S.A.**"

Se que puedo hacer `String.fromCharCode(parseInt("20", 16))` y me retornara el Carcter espacio o el que sea necesario , pero hay una forma mas sencilla, Gracias

Comment: Prueba con [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_decodeuricomponent)

Comment: Solucionado , Muchas gracias  @Triby , Funciona Correctamente.
Si tiene alguna sugerencia de modificar el Titulo de la pregunta , para ayudar alguna otra persona con la duda , seria de ayuda , Muchas gracias.